# react native: use with "KeyboardAwareScrollView" doesnt work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, keyboard

I try use the **KeyboardAwareScrollView** from [link](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view) and it doent work and donk know why .
I also tried working with "**KeyboardAvoidingView**" and it did not help.
I really do not understand where the problem is with me and would be happy for direction or help on the subject because every time the keyboard hides the text box and I do not understand how to deal with this problem.

this is my example :

```
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view'


function NetuneyDigum() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState('');
  const [isSelected, setSelection] = useState(false);

  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState('1');

  return (
    <>
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          alignItems: 'center',
          backgroundColor: '#cbced4',
        }}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            paddingTop: 30,
            flexDirection: 'row',
            paddingRight: 180,
          }}
        >
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: 'row',

              alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              left: 58,
            }}
          >
            <Text
              style={{
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: 18,
                color: 'black',
              }}
            >
              שעת דיגום:
            </Text>
          </View>
          <View
            style={{
              width: 150,
              borderRadius: 5,
              borderColor: 'black',
              borderWidth: 2,
              left: 80,
              alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              backgroundColor: 'white',
            }}
          >
            <Text
              style={{
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: 20,
                color: 'black',
              }}
            >
              {currentTime}
            </Text>
          </View>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              const time = moment().format('HH:mm');
              setCurrentTime(time);
            }}
            style={{
              height: 60,
              width: 60,
              borderRadius: 5,
              borderColor: 'black',
              borderWidth: 2,
              alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              backgroundColor: '#275d9f',
              left: 100,
            }}
          >
            <Icon size={40} color="white" name="time-outline" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: 'row',
            alignSelf: 'flex-start',
            // alignItems: 'flex-start',
            top: 40,
            left: 10,
          }}
        >
          <CheckBox
            value={isSelected}
            onValueChange={setSelection}
            style={styles.checkbox}
            tintColors={{ true: 'blue', false: 'black' }}
          />
          <Text style={styles.label}>שאיבת חוץ</Text>
        </View>
        <View
          style={{
            alignSelf: 'center',
            backgroundColor: '#275d9f',
            height: 50,
            width: 400,
            borderRadius: 5,
            borderColor: 'black',
            borderWidth: 2,
            top: 50,
          }}
        >
          <Text style={styles.Notice}>הערות</Text>
        </View>

        <KeyboardAwareScrollView
          behaviour="position"
          style={styles.container}
          enabled
        >
          <TextInput
            style={{
              top: 50,
              alignSelf: 'center',
              height: 200,
              width: 400,
              backgroundColor: 'white',
              borderWidth: 2,
              borderRadius: 5,
              fontSize: 18,
            }}
            placeholder="כתוב כאן.."
            // onChangeText={(text) => onChangeText(text)}
            // value={value5}
          />
        </KeyboardAwareScrollView>

        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: 'row',
            alignItems: 'flex-end',
            alignSelf: 'flex-start',
            bottom: 70,
            // paddingTop: 50,
          }}
        >
          <Text style={styles.label}>מעבדה:</Text>
          <View
            style={{
              borderWidth: 2,
              borderRadius: 5,
              backgroundColor: 'white',
              left: 15,
            }}
          >
            <Picker
              mode="dropdown"
              selectedValue={selectedValue}
              style={{
                placeholderTextColor: 'black',
                height: 50,
                width: 220,
                justifyContent: 'flex-end',
                transform: [{ scaleX: 1.2 }, { scaleY: 1.2 }],
                left: 15,
              }}
              onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
                setSelectedValue(itemValue)
              }
            >
              <Picker.Item label="ראש העין" value="1" />
              <Picker.Item label="מעבדה חיפה" value="2" />
              <Picker.Item label="מעבדה נס ציונה" value="3" />
            </Picker>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping all the elements inside `KeyboardAwareScrollView` not just the `TextInput`.
Try using something like this:

```
function NetuneyDigum() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState('');
  const [isSelected, setSelection] = useState(false);

  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState('1');

  return (
    <KeyboardAwareScrollView behaviour="position" enabled>
      <View
        style={{
          paddingTop: 30,
          flexDirection: 'row',
          paddingRight: 180,
        }}>
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: 'row',

            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            left: 58,
          }}>
          <Text
            style={{
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              fontSize: 18,
              color: 'black',
            }}>
            שעת דיגום:
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View
          style={{
            width: 150,
            borderRadius: 5,
            borderColor: 'black',
            borderWidth: 2,
            left: 80,
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            backgroundColor: 'white',
          }}>
          <Text
            style={{
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              fontSize: 20,
              color: 'black',
            }}>
            {currentTime}
          </Text>
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            const time = moment().format('HH:mm');
            setCurrentTime(time);
          }}
          style={{
            height: 60,
            width: 60,
            borderRadius: 5,
            borderColor: 'black',
            borderWidth: 2,
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            backgroundColor: '#275d9f',
            left: 100,
          }}>
          <Icon size={40} color="white" name="time-outline" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          alignSelf: 'flex-start',
          // alignItems: 'flex-start',
          top: 40,
          left: 10,
        }}>
        <CheckBox
          value={isSelected}
          onValueChange={setSelection}
          style={styles.checkbox}
          tintColors={{ true: 'blue', false: 'black' }}
        />
        <Text style={styles.label}>שאיבת חוץ</Text>
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          alignSelf: 'center',
          backgroundColor: '#275d9f',
          height: 50,
          width: 400,
          borderRadius: 5,
          borderColor: 'black',
          borderWidth: 2,
          top: 50,
        }}>
        <Text style={styles.Notice}>הערות</Text>
      </View>

      <TextInput
        style={{
          top: 50,
          alignSelf: 'center',
          height: 200,
          width: 400,
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          borderWidth: 2,
          borderRadius: 5,
          fontSize: 18,
        }}
        placeholder="כתוב כאן.."
        // onChangeText={(text) => onChangeText(text)}
        // value={value5}
      />

      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          alignItems: 'flex-end',
          alignSelf: 'flex-start',
          bottom: 70,
          // paddingTop: 50,
        }}>
        <Text style={styles.label}>מעבדה:</Text>
        <View
          style={{
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderRadius: 5,
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            left: 15,
          }}>
          <Picker
            mode="dropdown"
            selectedValue={selectedValue}
            style={{
              placeholderTextColor: 'black',
              height: 50,
              width: 220,
              justifyContent: 'flex-end',
              transform: [{ scaleX: 1.2 }, { scaleY: 1.2 }],
              left: 15,
            }}
            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
              setSelectedValue(itemValue)
            }>
            <Picker.Item label="ראש העין" value="1" />
            <Picker.Item label="מעבדה חיפה" value="2" />
            <Picker.Item label="מעבדה נס ציונה" value="3" />
          </Picker>
        </View>
      </View>
    </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
  );
}
```

Comment: can u show your meaning ? show my your example in my code and i will see if its work or not .

Comment: i did the wrapping all the code and now its make some mix in my screen elements

Comment: what do you mean `it make some mix in my screen`

Comment: now the keyboard just hide half if the text input,, how i can fix it ?

Comment: this is the link : https://snack.expo.io/@roei133/4b2e89

Comment: Maybe a working snack.expo.io ? Also I did manage to get it working a bit and `KeyboardAwareScrollView` is working ok, you just have some styling problems